# TypeError: Cannot convert null to object"

Tags: json, typescript, tsx

I'm having trouble accessing my json file, getting the error: "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object". I understand the error, the issue is that I cannot access the file more than once, as you can see from the json file, the challenge "8738-37cc" is completed, but the error occurs when I try to complete the second challenge.

```
/**
   * Retrieve the tasks for the current challenge from the API
   * Updates the Guide State with the retrieved tasks
   */
  function fetchTasks() {
    //Build API Endpoint based on current challenge in Application State
    const fetchURL = appContext.data.challenges && appContext.data.currentChallenge !== undefined
        ? `${APIUrl}challenge/${appContext.data.challenges[appContext.data.currentChallenge]}`
        : "";


    fetch(fetchURL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        setGuideState({
          ...guideState,
          loaded: true,
          data: json,
          tasks: Object.entries(json.tasks),
        });
      })
      .catch((ERROR) => console.error(`API challenge ERROR (${ERROR})`));
  }
```

This is my interface:

```
export interface AppStateType{
  challenges?: string[];
  currentChallenge?: number;
  globalLoadedState: boolean;
  overlay: "none"|"intro"|"outro";
  nextChallenge: ()=>void;
}
export let AppContext = React.createContext<{data: AppStateType, setData: any}>({data:{globalLoadedState:false, overlay:"none", nextChallenge: () => {}}, setData: ()=>{}});
```

This is the json file I'm trying to access:

```
{"8738-38dd":
{"title":"Passwords",
"definition":"Lorem ipsum passwords.....",
"isCompleted":false,
"TaskIDs":["8275-gm12","8275-hu99","8275-io91","8275-ja55","8275-kq31"]},

"8738-37cc":
{"title":"Updates",
"definition":"Lorem ipsum updates.....",
"isCompleted":true,
"TaskIDs":["8275-42ae","8275-ad69","8275-ba67","8275-cb44","8275-dn31","8275-en12","8275-fr56"]}}
```

Comment: You are accessing `Object.entries(json.tasks)` but `json.tasks` is undefined. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a json file with a bunch of tasks that I am trying to load into a Guide component, however only the first bunch of tasks load in, after that I cannot fetch the others.

Comment: Your json file does not have a property `tasks`. So you won't be able to access it...

Comment: My bad, should have included in the post, but json.tasks is defined earlier as: import Task from "./Guide/Tasks/Task"; But the compiler never gets to that point, as it is the "fetch(url) that fails.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't help. I guess, you'd need to provide the right pieces of code, that reproduce the issue then.